# LVM fills all remaining disk space, but not enough space on root partition

Tags: fedora, fdisk

I am inexperienced with Linux. I am running Fedora 25 Server, with default partitioning.

Following is the output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 977M     0  977M   0% /dev
tmpfs                    989M     0  989M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    989M  780K  988M   1% /run
tmpfs                    989M     0  989M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   15G   15G  8.5M 100% /
tmpfs                    989M  4.0K  989M   1% /tmp
/dev/sda5                976M  104M  806M  12% /boot
tmpfs                    198M     0  198M   0% /run/user/1000
```

How can I expand `/dev/mapper/fedora-root`?

**Update** -- output of `lsblk`:

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0              11:0    1   1.9G  0 rom
sda               8:0    0 149.1G  0 disk
├─sda4            8:4    0   450M  0 part
├─sda2            8:2    0   100M  0 part
├─sda5            8:5    0     1G  0 part /boot
├─sda3            8:3    0     1K  0 part
├─sda1            8:1    0   241M  0 part
└─sda6            8:6    0 147.3G  0 part
  ├─fedora-swap 253:1    0   2.1G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─fedora-root 253:0    0    15G  0 lvm  /
```

Comment: Please add the output of `lsblk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning: not tested, no guarantee. Assuming the default xfs filesystem.

First you have to increase the space allocated for the "root" logical volume on the "fedora" volume group. E.g. this will add another 10 gigabytes:

`lvresize -L +10G /dev/mapper/fedora-root`

Then you can resize the filesystem itself:

`xfs_growfs /`

Comment: I used `lvextend` in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your position I'd think about 2 possible solutions to your full-root-partition problem.

First, can I afford to, say, double the initial size of my root partition (i.e., have it >25GB, or even 40GB). Maybe that would solve the problem at hand (quick-and-dirty).

Second, and probably this is going to be more involved, what exactly does consume my root space? Is it the logs? In a modern BTRFS is it the snapshots?

In my opinion, when it comes to server systems, a 15GB root partition is not plenty of space in the first place, is it?

One more point. How about usage of a possible /opt directory, if that is supposed to expand considerably as time goes by (i.e., lots of software to be installed), perhaps /opt's contents could be moved to another physical disc and mounted from there as the /opt on your root system.

Regards, Micha

Comment: How would I go about the first option? `lvresize` + `xfs_growfs` as in [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355419/223974) answer?